# Referring a VF page outside the managed packaged into a managed package's global invocable class invoked from a flow

Tags: visualforce, managed-package

My managed package contains a global invocable method that generates a PDF and attaches it to a case record. I want my subcriber orgs to have the freedom to style/customomize the PDF. We are using VF pages rendered as PDF to generate this.

My code works well with VF pages which are part of managed package but fails when a PDF API name is passed as a parameter.

`pageReference p = new Pagereference('/apex/'+ OutsidePackageVisualForceAPIName);`  Fails

`pageReference p = new Pagereference('/apex/'+ ManagedPackageNameSpace + InsidePackageVisualForceAPIName);`  Passes

The error I am getting says 'You have attempted to reach a page that no longer exists'

Can anyone help guide me on why this won't work?

Please note that the same code works just fine when run in a unpackaged org.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Every namespace executes Visualforce in its own domain name. Let's say that `ns` is your namespace, the domain looks like `ns.vf.force.com/apex/pageName`. This subdomain structure forces all relative references (as written here) to be in the namespace as the package. This is true both in your packaging org and any subscriber org. `Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` should return a URL that points to the subscriber's actual domain that you can use to reference their page.